# How to debug AlertManager?

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I have configured Alertmanager to send a mail everytime an alert is triggered. However for an unknow reason I'm not receiving any mail.

How can I debug this? Is there a log file stored somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How have you started the Alertmanager? The tool should show the warnings/errors in the terminal. You can start the Alertmanager redirecting the output to a log file like in the following example:

```
ALERTMANAGER-INSTALL-PATH/alertmanager >> ALERTMANAGER-LOG-PATH/alertmanager.log 2>&1 &
```

If you're running the Alertmanager inside a Docker container try to use the Docker logs.

Comment: It is actually running inside a Docker Container. Can I set the log file redirection inside the configuration file?

Comment: I think this will help you: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-redirect-command-output-from-docker-container/49758/2

Comment: I used 'docker logs' to view logs of standard output. Thanks for your help.